# Delete border space around GridView

Tags: android, gridview, border

I try to remove red border around **GridView** to completely fill screen my calendar(without padding from left, right and top).

```
margin=0
padding=0
background=@null
```

isn't fix the problem.
I don't use any 9path background image.
what's the problem ?

[image]

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Your "issue" is the `selector`.
You can change it using: [android:listSelector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:listSelector).

You can try removing the selector with `android:listSelector="@null` or creating a custom one. [Here](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/08/making-prettier-buttons-in-android-xml-rolloverselection-focus-effects-9patch-images-and-transparency/)'s a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The following sets the color around the image to white:

`android:listSelector="@drawable/solid_white"`