# How to manage GridView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have following code for Gridview (To make the Calendar).

```
    <GridView
    android:id="@+id/calendar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/rl1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ll2"
    android:columnWidth="250dp"
    android:numColumns="7" >
    </GridView>
```

Grid_Cell is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/calendar_day_gridcell"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="14.47sp" >
</Button>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/num_events_per_day"
    style="@style/calendar_event_style"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >
</TextView>
```

I want to set no space between the rows and columns. [image: like this]

Existing view is as following.

[image: Existing image]

Please help me out... Thanks in Advance
.

Comment: Take a look here (look to properties like "clipChildren", "verticalSpacing", etc...): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705330/gridview-and-excess-space-padding

Comment: @kinghomer not working... sorry

Comment: Can you post your row layout?

Comment: @Luksprog Question edited and gridcell added... now look pls

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't add any padding in those drawables used for the `Button`'s background. How do you inflate the row layout in the `getView` method? Do you use `inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridcelllayout, parent, false);`?

Comment: No. Can you give me complete view of code

Comment: I don't know what code to show you. In the `getView` method try to inflate the grid cell layout by using the `ViewGroup` parameter of the `getView` method and using `false` as the parameter for the `inflate` method of the `LayoutInflater`.

Comment: I would advice you to set the columnWidth on Runtime according to the screen width. And your adapter should be fed with the column width and height to set them when inflating child views. And in this case, you need to get rid of numColumns. Remember that using numColumns along with columnWidth makes no sense especially when you want to fill the whole space. If you want to set the numColumns, remove the columnWidth.

Comment: @SherifelKhatib i want it to be dynamically... please suggest some code for that.

Comment: I will try to give you a snippet, but to be honest, there is no point of using a GridView for your case since all you items are there on the screen anyway. You can create a couple of LinearLayouts in a small loop that will get the result. Would that suit you?

Comment: For making calender we just need grid view... easily manageable..

Comment: follow this link http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will try to give you a snippet, but to be honest, there is no point of using a GridView for your case since all you items are there on the screen anyway. You can create a couple of `LinearLayout`s in a small loop that will get the result.

I would advice you to set the columnWidth on Runtime according to the screen width.

And your adapter should be fed with the column width and height to set them when inflating child views. And in this case, you need to get rid of numColumns. Remember that using numColumns along with columnWidth makes no sense especially when you want to fill the whole space. If you want to set the numColumns, remove the columnWidth.

**SOLUTION**:

Here is the outcome:
[image]
First, we create our layout. In my case, it is the `MainActivity`'s layout and is called `activity_main.xml`. (Notice there is no GridView because I'll add that later in code):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:background="#444"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Dynamic Static GridView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#444"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Shush" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Our GridView element's layout is here in the `item_grid.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now the trick is in MainActivity (I have commented some of the code for you to understand):

package com.example.dynamicstaticgridview;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;

/**
 * @author Sherif elKhatib
 *
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static String items[]; //these are temporary items :p do not use them
    static {
        items = new String[7*7];
        for(int i=0;i<7*7;i++) {
            items[i] = String.valueOf(i);
        }
    }

    int numberOfColumns = 7; //defaulting to 7, you can change it when you know
    int numberOfRows = 7; //defaulting to 7, you can change it when you know
    GridView mGrid;
    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.header);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.footer);
        mGrid = new GridView(this) {
            @Override
            protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
                super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
                if(!calculated)
                    getDimens();
            }
        };
        mGrid.setVerticalSpacing(0);
        mGrid.setHorizontalSpacing(0);
        mGrid.setStretchMode(GridView.NO_STRETCH);
        mGrid.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(100, 10, 10));
        ((RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rootview)).addView(mGrid, params);
    }

    private int mCellWidth;
    private int mCellHeight;
    boolean calculated = false;
    protected void getDimens() {
        calculated = true;
        //here you might have some rounding errors
        //thats why you see some padding around the GridView
        mCellWidth = mGrid.getWidth()/numberOfColumns;
        mCellHeight = mGrid.getHeight()/numberOfRows;
        mGrid.setColumnWidth(mCellWidth);
        mGrid.setNumColumns(numberOfColumns);
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item_grid, R.id.text, items) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                GridView.LayoutParams params = null;
                if(convertView == null) {
                    params = new GridView.LayoutParams(mCellWidth, mCellHeight);
                }
                convertView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                if(params != null) {
                    convertView.setLayoutParams(params);
                }
                return convertView;
            }
        };
        mGrid.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

**COMMENTS**:
You'd really better find a decent algorithm to choose `mCellWidth`, `mCellHeight`, `numberOfColumns`, and `numberOfRows`.

Answer (score 4):

I might be wrong but as far as I know the [`GridView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) is an `AdapterView`, which in your case means that you can't dynamically, through xml, format the height of your items in a way so that they always fill the entire parent. That is not the way grid views (and list views and other adapter views) work.

These kind of "scrollable container views" could be seen as [microfilm readers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microfilm_reader) that used to exist in "modern libraries" a very long time ago. One needs to realize that the data has really nothing to do with the actual viewer, you just use your viewer (the `GridView` in your case) with a fix with and height to pan over the underlaying data items which also have their fix widths and heights.

As I see it you're trying to explicitly target the very corner-case where the data just happens to have the same geometric size as your viewer window.

***A few tips, though:***

You could instead have a look at [`GridLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html). The `GridLayout` is introduced in API level 14 (IceCream Sandwich) so you might have to rethink your version support strategy there (if I'm not completely misstaking it should also be included in the v7 support package for backwards compatibility on older platforms, in that case you could simply add the jar to your app to support older API levels).

Yet another tip would be to use a [`TableLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) with corresponding table rows and what not. The `TableLayout` has been around from day one, so there is no backward compataibility issues there, but they do tend to become very layout intensive, though. If you are planning to reload your view a lot or scroll between months smoothly, I'm not sure this is the solution for you (due to the amount of deep layout routes).

A third solution would be that you still use the `GridView`, but you measure the height of it and dynamically set a fix height to your inflated grid view items from your grid view adapter, based on the measured `GridView` height (In other words: you make sure you enter the above mentioned corner-case).

If you use the `GridView` you'd need to get rid of the vertical spacing as well. There is a `android:stretchMode` attribute on the `GridView` which you could [play around with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108571/how-to-get-rid-of-spaces-in-gridview). You could also try different (negative?) dimensions on the `android:verticalSpacing` attribute.

Good luck with your custom calendar view!

Comment: Do you have any built-in margin and/or padding in the `calendar_button_selector` drawable?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to give a height and width to your gridview put a relative layout outside of the gridview and give android:layout_width and android:layout_height to your relative layout. Then give your gridview's width and height to match_parent. After that if you want to give exact height and width to your gridview cell elements at first you have to know the exact width and height of all cells and you should define the columnWidth according to that, for example for this code

```
 <GridView
android:id="@+id/calendar"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_above="@+id/rl1"
android:layout_below="@+id/ll2"
android:columnWidth="250dp"
android:numColumns="7" >
</GridView>
```

if you dont have 1000dp layout outside you never get 4 cells in one row in a good view but only gridview will try to determine its own cell width.

for your situation your calendar gridview should be something like this:

```
<GridView
android:id="@+id/calendar"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_above="@+id/rl1"
android:layout_below="@+id/ll2"
android:columnWidth="50dp"
android:numColumns="7" >
</GridView>
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a solution for you http://www.anddev.org/how_to_display_gridview_with_gridlines_and_borders-t11099.html

Answer (score 1):

Try setting these two values in XML for your `GridView`:

```
android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
```

You'll probably want to remove the `android:columnWidth` field.