# How to remove border around grid-view

Tags: android

Here is my grid view layout where I have tried to use `android:listSelector="@null"`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#191919">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:columnWidth="100dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:listSelector="@null"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

But  I can't get rid of these black borders in my grid-view

[image]

Comment: the black color is the color of your gridview

Comment: but when i scroll up or down, the black border is overlapping the green

Comment: please post your xml layout that contains gridlayout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete border space around GridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291265/delete-border-space-around-gridview)

Comment: @PhanVănLinh Okay thanks anyways, you basically helped me figure it out.

Comment: @the_prole you are wellcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
android:horizontalSpacing="0dp" 
android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change it using: android:listSelector.

You can try removing the selector with android:listSelector="@null

```
<!-- Setting the listSelector to null removes the 5px border -->
<GridView
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:listSelector="@null" />
```

If it doesn't work add android:fadingEdgeLength="0px" to your GridView

```
<GridView
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fadingEdgeLength="0px"
android:listSelector="@null" />
```

Or, in Java:

```
GridView.setFadingEdgeLength(0);
```